# Several Facebook Like button on a page

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am looking to place many Facebook like buttons on a page which i want they to allow me to post to facebook wall of the user who logins through them. Can some one point me on where to find this workflow for .NET. I wish the user clicks on a Like button log ins then with the access token post to wall the content. later if he clicks on other like button it will just post to wall: image test,...
Is this possible? whew can i find code example?
thanks in advance

Comment: Just go here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ copy de code, and paste it as many times you like changing only the url of the like button

Comment: Thanks, but this does not give me a token to use the API to send the items to the timeline....

Comment: no, for that you must create an app on https://developers.facebook.com, then ask the user for permissions whenever he enters your website, in case he hasn't granted yet and after all you've done this, you can use the javascript sdk to listen for the like event, whenever a user presses a like button you get the response, do an ajax request to your server store it on the database and later you can post on behalf of the user the content he liked